# No lockscreen option in CCSM 14.04

Tags: unity, lightdm, 14.04, lock-screen, ccsm

I expected to find Lockscreen option in CCSM after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, in Unity Plugin, general section, in order to switch between unity and lightdm.
Unfortunately, It's not in the tab.

Why?

Comment: I have the same problem in 16.04, did you found any solution?

Comment: It seems that such option was simply abandoned / dismissed. No explains by canonical, no bugs, nothing... Simply disappeared...
Microsoft-ish behaviour;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked around, even in the source of Unity, and it does not seem like there is a way to do this.

Obviously, the Ubuntu developers don't share the opinions in http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/toolkits.html, but they should respect that others might do, and not prevent users from choosing their own screensaver. Several bugs has been found already in the new lockscreen.